# SQL regexp to include NOT in search pattern

Tags: sql, regex

I would like to run the following query to search email pattern:

```
select * from users
where email regexp  Binary '[a-z]*[0-9][0-9][0-9]@yahoo.com';
```

I would like to find all email strings which has x alphabetic, 3 digits exactly and ends with @yahoo.com:

```
example123@yahoo.com
admin754@yahoo.com
```

But current query also return strings with 3+ digits such as `example45653@yahoo.com`
How can this be done?

Comment: Are we talking MySQL here?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? Functions for regular expressions different greatly between each DBMS.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use `not`:

```
where not (email regexp Binary '[a-z]*[0-9][0-9][0-9]@yahoo.com')
```

or

```
where (email not regexp Binary '[a-z]*[0-9][0-9][0-9]@yahoo.com')
```

The one caveat:  `NULL` values for `email` will fail both tests, as well as the original.

Answer (score 0):

You should put anchors on the regex and do it as follows:

`^[a-zA-Z]+\d{3}@yahoo\.com$`

[**DEMO**](http://regex101.com/r/rC8hT8)

Comment: you said it was impossible!

Comment: @AmitJoki, Once upon a time yes! And by the way, I saw that comment ;)

Comment: A POSIX Extended RE cannot match the start and the end of a line with `^` and `$`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE mycolumn REGEXP "[a-zA-Z]+[[:digit:]]{3}@yahoo\\.com";
```

***LIVE DEMO***

http://regex101.com/r/tK1sS7

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
\b[a-z]+[0-9]{3}@yahoo\.com\b
```

For more samples have a look at below links:

- [Regular Expressions Make Pattern Matching And Data Extraction Easier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx)
- [How to Find or Validate an Email Address](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html)